# Brew Formula install with multiple files

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've created a python tool and want to install it via brew. Creating the formula worked fine at first when i simply had one python file named myTool. Then i seperated the code into more files as it became larger and more complex.

How do i set up the install to bundle those files, because right now the imports are failing because the other files are not found.

My current install

```rb
  def install
    bin.install 'myTool'
  end
```

The error shown when running the brew installed tool

> from myModule import someFunc, someOtherFunc ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myModule'

Comment: Your current setup is installing just the binary (hence `bin.install`), without any of the additional python files. Would you mind describing your file structure? If you have a `setup.py`, you can use `virtualenv_install_with_resources`.

Comment: Yes that was also my understanding, but i just don't know the syntax to get those file moved along. It's open source anyway. https://github.com/Deitsch/angler/ and https://github.com/Deitsch/homebrew-angler/.

Comment: Thanks for sending the links. I think I have something working :) I'll send it over as a PR, and I'll also submit an answer here explaining it.

Comment: The legend <3. Thanks a lot already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current setup only installs the `angler` file without any of the other python modules. This results in the `ModuleNotFoundError` error. Here is my suggestion:

```rb
def install
  # Determines the python version being used
  # e.g. If python3.10, xy = 3.10
  xy = Language::Python.major_minor_version "python3"
  # Where to install the python files
  packages = libexec/"lib/python#{xy}/site-packages/angler"

  # For each file present, install them in the right location
  %w[angler anglerEnums.py anglerGen.py anglerHelperFunctions.py].each do |file|
    packages.install file
  end

  # Create a symlink to the angler python file
  bin.install_symlink packages/"angler"
end
```

Comment: I added some questions to the MR, but for the SO post, this is definitely good enough to be accepted. Thanks!